# Typescript error when defining property as ObjectId in Mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm writing interface and schema in mongoose, but got some typescript error:

```js
import { Schema, Types } from 'mongoose';

interface Foo {
  _id: Types.ObjectId,
  bar: Types.ObjectId,
}

const FooSchema = new Schema<Foo>({
  _id: { type: Types.ObjectId },
  bar: { type: Types.ObjectId },
});
```

both property `_id` and `bar` has typescript error in this code:

```
Type '{ type: typeof Types.ObjectId; }' is not assignable to type 'SchemaDefinitionProperty | undefined'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'typeof ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'typeof Mixed | ObjectIdSchemaDefinition | undefined'.
      Type 'typeof ObjectId' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof Mixed': schemaName, cast, checkRequired, set, get
```

The mongoose version is 6.5.4 (which is currently the latest version available)

I have no idea why. It's not the first time to me to write mongoose schema, but didn't have any problems like this.

I've confirmed that I can reproduce this error from clean new project. (means that there's no other background reason)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here, try changing your schema type definitions like so:

```
const FooSchema = new Schema<Foo>({
  _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  bar: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
});
```

**Explanation:**

According to the Mongoose documentation, a SchemaType is different from a regular type. In other words, `mongoose.ObjectId !== mongoose.Types.ObjectId`. I.E the SchemaType `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` is a special definition used by Mongoose. The regular type definition `Types.ObjectId` can be used to create Interfaces, but the SchemaType must be used when creating a schema. It's slightly confusing yes. Just like SchemaType `String` must be used in a Schema instead of `string` in an Interface even though both are technically type definitions. Hope this helps!